# Weird padding issue in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am working on a jQuery slider for a web page. Everything looks great in IE, but in Chrome and Firefox, there is some kind of weird padding issue going on above and below the slider.

EDITED: See my solution in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woot! I figured it out. There was a "display: table" line in the CSS that was jacking it up. Removed that, and it works fine now.

Comment: Yes, it is fixed. I changed the Doctype, and it makes no difference. Your issues with IE sound like a personal problem to me.

Comment: I see you're one of those people that can't handle being wrong. So be it.

Answer (score 1):

Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work. Always, always use any other browser first. THEN look to see how IE screws things up.

Your doctype is incorrect for the modern web and puts IE, and other browsers, into "quirks mode" where you never want to be. Then you marked up your page with that browser, assuming IE, that's pretending it's 1998 all over again. Change your doctype to this one `<!DOCTYPE html>` and use Firefox or Chrome to correct your markup cause, then, even IE will look different. Yes, it might only mean making adjustments or, possibly, starting all over again.

This is not including your 13 HTML validation errors and 14 CSS errors.